# csv file imports only the last row when imported in drupal 8 webform

Tags: webforms

I have a csv file which contains the entries from drupal 7 webform. I uploaded the csv file in drupal 8 webform. It imports the data, but only the last entry is shown in the drupal 8 webform's results.

This is the csv file:
columns A-D : IP Add, UUID, Phone Number, Email.  (dummy entries).

[image]

When importing the mapping from the csv file, it shows me the below options:
[image]

I select the matching columns on the destination(submission) and then click import.
After importing this is what drupal displays:

[image]

Only the last row from the csv file is updated in the webform.

Answer (score 0):

The UUID for all your CSV records is 1 and when they are being imported, each row is overwriting the previous row. You also need to include the column headers as the first row in the CSV.

Comment: I included column headers as the first row in the CSV. But still, it imports the last row only. How can I make the UUID different for each row ?

Comment: UUID by definition must be unique. If you are exporting the information from Drupal 7, try using https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_submission_uuid

Comment: Ok. I'll try this. Thank you. But can you explain how come my UUID is 1 for all the submissions ?

Comment: I don't know why your UUID is 1 for all the submissions.  If you remove the UUID column, your submissions will import as expected.

Comment: I had to manually change the uuid in csv file. but when I used `drush webform:generate` to generate random submissions, the uuid that were generated for each submission were in this format. `6435f33e-5013-4717-88d5-395a08a661b2`